# MS Band Tile - Chevron Indicator

Tags: microsoft-band

I am developing an Android app that uses the MS Band 2. Is there a way I could display a "Chevron Indicator" in my customized layouts ?

[image: Screenshot of the chevron indicator]

The Microsoft Band 2 Experience Design Guidelines states the following, p. 16:

> When there are button options to the right, there is an arrow peek indicator.

and I'd like to follow this rule if it is possible.